# Windows Ubuntu and Zathura

Tags: windows-10, vim, zathura

I am trying to set up zathura on Windows 10 by using Ubuntu as available from the microsoft store. I would like to use Zathura as my PDF viewer when writing with vim/vimtex, and am currently facing the issue:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (zathura:10420): 
Gtk-WARNING **: 15:58:19.628: cannot open display :0
```

This occurs when I type `zathura` into an Ubuntu terminal. I am new (and struggling) with Ubuntu and have only done the following:

1) I downloaded Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store

2) I opened terminal, and typed `vim`. This successfully launches

3) `sudo-apt get update`

4) `sudo-apt get zathura`

5) typing `zathura` produces the error mentioned above.

I've been google searching for a few days, but I think my unfamiliarity with this technology has made spotting an appropriate solution difficult.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install zathura` or just `sudo apt-get zathura`? If you do not have the install factor, the software will not be, well, installed.

Comment: I just typed `sudo apt-get install zathura`, which is performed successfully, and the error remains. Thank you for your edits and suggestion.

Comment: WSL does not come with an X server for GUI applications. If you need to run Zathura on WSL (not recommended), you can check out various X server solutions for Windows, including XMing and vcxsrv.

Comment: I see. Thanks for identifying the main issue. Now I can explore options

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. My solution is to use the google chrome browser.

```
# step 1
sudo ln /path/to/your/chrome/in/windows /usr/bin/chrome
# e.g., /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe

# step 2 add the following line in your ~/.vimrc
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer='chrome'
```

However, there is still a little problem that every time you preview the compiled pdf file, it always open a new tab in chrome instead of the previous pdf tab.

Comment: You might need to quote `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe` since it contain whitespaces.